# problema con Input tipo button de login

Tags: css, bootstrap, login

Tengo el siguiente Login el cual tome de un ejemplo que vi en internet ya que me gusto mucho. Al poner el usuario y contraseña lo normal es que si uno de los dos es incorrecto te muestre un mensaje diciendo "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", pero en algunos navegadores no hace nada, como si no seleccionaras el botón "Iniciar Sesión". Esto depende el equipo que se este utilizando por ejemplo en una computadora no entra con Chrome pero si en Mozilla y en otra computadora es al revés. Lo normal es que el botón "Iniciar Sesión" sea del mismo tamaño que el input "Usuario" y "Contraseña". Al principio pensé que era un problema con la carga de bootstrap ya que tenia mal acomodados los link pero ya los acomode y sigue igual, despues pense que era la nueva politica de google en cuanto a las cookies pero tampoco es. Hace poco observe que tengo este problema cuando al cargar la pagina el botón "Iniciar Sesión" se cargar normal pero unos segundos después se hace mas pequeño.
Agradecería infinitamente si pudieran ayudarme de antemano gracias!!!

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/fondol.png");
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}

div {
    background-image: url("img/fondo.jpg");
}

.user_card {
    height: 400px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.brand_logo_container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 170px;
    width: 170px;
    top: -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.brand_logo {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px #dddddd;
}

.form_container {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.login_btn {
    width: 100%;
    background: #01239F !important;
    color: white !important;
}

.login_btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
}

.login_container {
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.input-group-text {
    background: #006FDA !important;
    color: white !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem !important;
}

.input_user,
.input_pass:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #c0392b !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/gtosanofavicon.png">
  <title>SIAHEG</title>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
    {
      header("Location: escritorio.php");
    }
    require "modulos/usuarios/usuario.php";
    ?>
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
            <div class="user_card">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="brand_logo_container">
                        <img src="img/gto_sano_logo.jpg" class="brand_logo" alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="container input-group " style="top:65px; text-align: center;">
          <h5 style="font-size:15px !important; color: blue;">Bienvenido</h5>
        </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">

                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span style="background: #4BC84A;" class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control input_user" value="" placeholder="Usuario">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <span style="background: #FDA11E;" class="input-group-text"><i  class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control input_pass" value="" placeholder="Contraseña">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                            
                                <p class="text-success text-center"><?php echo $mensaje ;?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3 login_container">
                    <input type="hidden" name="login">
                    <input type="submit" name="button" class="btn login_btn " value="Iniciar Sesion">
                </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estás usando la librería de Bootstrap 2 veces, solo deja 1. Tienes linkeados la versión 4.1.1 y la 4.1.3, puedes dejar sólo la última y actualizar tu JS a la misma versión

Comment: El jQuery también lo tienes repetido. Revisa eso y si sigues con la falla puedes [edit] tu pregunta